# Double summation including power and factorial

Tags: calculus, summation, factorial, exponentiation

I am finding some trouble in computing the following sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\;\sum_{m=0}^k\frac {y^m}{m!}$$

Could you please provide a result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure it's computable? I got to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(xy)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} x^k $ and can't see a way to get to the binomial expansion of $(x+xy)^n$